# how to pas parameters using Post to page in c#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, post

I have a website from which i have to login to another website.both websites accessing same DB. i know we can do it using DB but client is not accepting that. so we have create one intermediate page to do this. We tried it by sending data in query string. but when we are doing encryption the size becomes larger of URL. So i discussed with one senior lead he is in PHP team, he asked me to post data on website using POST method. I am not getting how i can do it.

Please suggest.

Below is my code:

Login Page on first website:

```
Response.Redirect(http://ghhghg.com/TestingLogin.aspx?jaj=" +hdfUserName.Value.Trim() + "&ghhhg=" + hdfpassword.Value.Trim();
```

And Page Load of "TestingLogin" page:

```
 string username = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["jaj"]))
    {
        username = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["jaj"]);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ghhhg"]))
    {
        password = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ghhhg"]);
    }
```

I have removed encryption from above code.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use his code is bettter to post in server side , I was using the code for few years,

c# Code

```
 public  string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
      //  req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
        //Add these, as we're doing a POST
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
        os.Close();
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        if (resp == null) return null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
```

I hope this will help you :)